# Count how many of each distinct item - trying to find most common

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the most common entry out of the last 10. I can find the distinct entries but I don't know how to count how many of each one.

The last 10 entries are

```
table
desk
desk
desk
chair
table
chair
desk
table
chair
```

The following SQL query can find the distinct entries

```
SELECT DISTINCT entry FROM `records` WHERE  custid ='464' LIMIT 10

table
chair
desk
```

I have tried

```
SELECT COUNT(entry) FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT entry FROM `records` 
  WHERE  custid ='464' LIMIT 10)
```

The above doesn't seem to work. What I am looking for is an sql query that will produce

```
table (3)
desk (4)
chair (3)
```

Can anybody find a way to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is `GROUP BY`(https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)
This particular problem could be solved by (considering entry is the column containing table,esk etc...)
     <strike>`SELECT entry,COUNT(*) FROM records WHERE custid ='464' GROUP BYentry LIMIT 10`</strike>

**Applying `LIMIT` directly with `GROUP BY` MySQL limits the rows per group** so the actual query was

```
`SELECT entry,COUNT(*) FROM (Select entry from records WHERE custid ='464' limit 10) GROUP BY entry`
```

Comment: No need for distinct sub query here; just count and group by

Comment: Thanks for your code.That works pretty good but the limit is for the distinct entries. Is there a way to have it search only the last 10 entries?

Comment: I thought it did but I was wrong. Try this 
`Select entry,count(*) from (select entry FROM records WHERE custid ='464' limit 10) group by entry`

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't work. It gave this error code. Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Change it to `Select entry,count(*) from (select entry FROM records WHERE custid ='464' limit 10) as tb group by tb.entry`

Comment: Awesome thanks. That final code does exactly as I would like

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT entry) as counts FROM records WHERE custid ='464' LIMIT 10
```